# Proper way to combine objective-c and c++?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm working on an app that will do some real time processing of input audio.  I found [this](http://teragonaudio.com/article/How-to-do-realtime-recording-with-effect-processing-on-iOS.html) site that I think I can use as a starting point.  However, all the functions provided are in C++.

The simplest thing I'd like to get going first is changing the text of a UILabel to some of the values received by the function:

```
OSStatus renderCallback(void *userData, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags,
                    const AudioTimeStamp *audioTimeStamp, UInt32 busNumber,
                    UInt32 numFrames, AudioBufferList *buffers)
```

I pasted all the functions into the @implementation of my view and was able to compile by changing the extension to .mm.  I created a UILabel property, but the renderCallback function can't access it.

Obviously just pasting those functions into the @implementation isn't the right way to be doing this.  How do I do it the right way?

Comment: The code on that page was apparently written by someone who wants to avoid the native language and libraries as much as possible.  Have you looked through Apple's Core Audio sample projects?

Answer (score 0):

Although C++ can basically go into a `.mm` file as-is, this doesn't always work (e.g. if you had a variable named `id` it would conflict with Objective-C).  You can alternately leave most of your C++ code in a separate file and just `#import` the appropriate C++ `.h` file into the `.mm` where you create a `UILabel`, etc.

As far as what a `UILabel` requires; you need to create an `NSString*` value.  One possibility is something like `stringWithFormat:`, e.g.

```
int myInt = 0;
const char *myString = "string";
id myObject = @"object";
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"here is a number: %d, here is a C string: %s, here is an object: %@", myInt, myString, myObject];
```

You can imagine grabbing whatever primitive values you want from your C++ code, and turning them into a single label value using a formatted string such as the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access objective-c variable in C/C++ method directly. Pass your object in `void *userData`.

```
-(void)Method
{
renderCallback(self, &actionFlags,
                    &audioTimeStamp, busNumber,
                    numFrames, &buffers);
}

OSStatus renderCallback(void *userData, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags,
                    const AudioTimeStamp *audioTimeStamp, UInt32 busNumber,
                    UInt32 numFrames, AudioBufferList *buffers)
{
id obj;
    if (userData)
   {
    obj = (id)userData;
    [obj MethodB];
   }
//....  

}
```